# An error occurred while installing Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: dual-boot

I was using Ubuntu version 20.04 alongside Windows 10 (dual boot) for quite a while and everything was fine. I installed new updates required and everything stopped, could not login to Ubuntu any longer. try to install the new version 20.04.1 LTS several times and nothing happening. I'am no longer able to install Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on my computer. I am getting this message:

An error occurred while installing packages:
E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 0):

it seems you have a problem with dpkg package manager , try installing ubuntu with the minimal installation , you can try formatting the previous installed ubuntu partition then try again.
also you can check this link
https://www.tecmint.com/sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-in-ubuntu/